# Showing Alert Dialog after Notification button tap

Tags: android, notifications, android-alertdialog

From within my Service, I've created a Notification with the `NotificationCompat.Builder`.  The notification is making use of `RemoteViews`.

Is it possible once the user taps the image button within the Notification to present my Main Activity and popup the Cancel alert dialog? The **Main Activity** could already be running since it did start the service.

At the moment I've resorted to having the Notification call my service and then from the service send an event to the Main Activity to open the Cancel alert dialog -- the alert dialog is opening -- but this approach does not collapse the expanded Notify drawer display nor does it pop up the Main Activity to present the alert dialog.  I'm looking to have the alert dialog appear without Notification drawer obstruction and the activity to be visible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the flow I think will work for you

1. When someone clicks on your notification. send a flag with intent to
   let `MainActivity` know that it is notification.
2. Open the `MainActivity`.
3. Check for the flag if flag is there: Execute your `AlertDialog`
                     if the flag is not there: skip the `DialoAlertDialoggBox` code.
4. Done.